# How to prevent Spotify from using port 80?

Tags: spotify, spotify-desktop

After running a `sudo lsof -i :80` I see Spotify running on port 80.
Well, darn it, since I already use this port for a web server, and Spotify obviously isn’t one. Why would they even consider this? Oh, I know, it has to do with firewalls probably.

Where would one change this setting (on a Mac)?

Comment: this is not really related to programming, you should move this over to super user

Comment: Thanks. Actually I asked Spotify support first, and they suggested I ask it here since they thought it is a developer question. In all honesty I think it is up to them, but they obviously do not have the resources.
I will not be moving the question myself. Anyone who has enough reputation is free to do it.